# Wireshark and http protocol

Tags: http, wireshark

I was wondering what steps would I would have to take to analyze a PCAP file in Wireshark if the PCAP file contained evidence of backdoor command and control via the HTTP protocol?

Answer (score 0):

Wireshark usually auto-detects http packets for you, but in case it does not, simply right-click on a packet and choose **Decode packet as** and choose `HTTP` from the popup dialog that appears.